# soap_call_<something> compilation error: "identifier not found"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, gsoap

I am trying to use gsoap 2.8 to connect a C++ plugin to several web services.
When I used it to connect to single service I got, among other, a function **soap_call_*KitPro*_GetDefectsByDateRange()**

Now that I have created a wsdl file containing several web services that my plugin should connect to, I see no functions starting with **soap_call_*** at all.

What may be the reason? what should I check?

Is there any other way to actually activate the connection to the service I need?

Thanks!

Comment: If you made a wsdl and when you compile the wsdl it doesn't produce a function you can call then something is probably wrong with the wsdl?

Comment: I managed to find the "missing" soap_call_* functions.
They are declared in the soapStubs.h file and for some reasons a number was added to them (actually they seem duplicated, with following numbers)

SOAP_FMAC5 int SOAP_FMAC6 soap_call___KitPro2__GetDefectsByDateRange(...);
SOAP_FMAC5 int SOAP_FMAC6 soap_call___KitPro3__GetDefectsByDateRange(...);

For now it gets compiled... hope it will also function as expected... :-)